# Swiper navigation not working - Webpack (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, webpack, swiper.js

Swiper is initializing without problems, for some reason, pagination (and everything else...) is not working.

I'm using webpack on laravel (5.8), the version of swiper i'm using is 6.4.5. No errors in console

This is my code:

```
// import Swiper JS
import Swiper, { Pagination } from 'swiper';
// import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';

// configure Swiper to use modules
Swiper.use([Pagination]);


var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
});
```

Outcome:
Swiper is created, pagination not working, autoplay not working, nothing is working only the swiper is created

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue, I'll post my answer if anyones has the same problem.

The version of swiper i'm currently using contains the vue integration, I'm not using the vue integration because i'm working with the version 2 of vue.js, swiper needs the version 3 of vue.js. So I commended out my vue instance, and everything started working, the issue was a conflict between vue.js and Swiper.

In the documentation you import the same way for vue and ES modules so i'm guessing there is some type of conflict.

So I moved my swiper import after the vue.js declaration:

```
/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});

require('./scripts/swiper');
```

And now everything is working